# Enumerate over indices without values in rust

Tags: rust

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```rust
for i in collection.iter().enumerate().map(|(i, _)| i) {...}
```

In other words I'm looking for a method like `enumerate` but which only gives the indices, not the values. Something like

```rust
for i in collection.iter().indices() {...}
```

Does such a method exist?

Comment: Use a range, `for i in 0..collection.len()`.

Comment: If there's no length function then there's no built-in way as far as I know, since discarding the values of an iterator completely is a situation so rare that it shouldn't get a stdlib function.

Comment: @Aplet123 fair enough, I suppose it is a pretty rare scenario where this is desirable.

Comment: why not just `for (i, _) in ... enumerate()` ?

Comment: @eggyal because I want to chain a bunch of other methods but I don't want to type `|(i, _)|` in each closure, I want to just type `|i|`.

Comment: It’d probably help if you showed that in your question, rather than `for ... in` loops then :-) but even moreso, it’d probably help to have a broader understanding of how you’re using this as this problem as described is a bit of code smell IMHO...

Answer (score 4):

> I want to chain a bunch of other methods but I don't want to type `|(i, _)|` in each closure, I want to just type `|i|`
> [...]
> Does such a method exist?

No, but you can write an extension trait that provides one ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=968a1713710f6ac276b2e820de906e92)):

```
trait IndicesExt<I> {
    fn indices(self) -> Indices<I>;
}

struct Indices<I> {
    next: usize,
    iter: I,
}

impl<I: Iterator> IndicesExt<I> for I {
    fn indices(self) -> Indices<I> {
        Indices {
            next: 0,
            iter: self,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for Indices<I> {
    type Item = usize;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        if let Some(_) = self.iter.next() {
            let current = self.next;
            self.next += 1;
            Some(current)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation can be simplified by reusing the `Enumerate` iterator returned by `Iterator::enumerate()` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7ef14701f95e06c8d0b5354cc12b3ce)):

```
struct Indices<I>(std::iter::Enumerate<I>);

impl<I: Iterator> IndicesExt<I> for I {
    fn indices(self) -> Indices<I> {
        Indices(self.enumerate())
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for Indices<I> {
    type Item = usize;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        self.0.next().map(|(idx, _)| idx)
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha yes I know I could write one. I don't think I'd ever use this enough to justify it over `enumerate().map(|(i, _)| i)` though.

Comment: @MichaelDorst Well, with sufficient number of such closures, who knows. :)